# Are object storage objects technically object oriented class instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, object-storage, cloud-object-storage

While every guide describes object storage objects as data with metaproperties, can they also be referred to as objects (i.e. class instantiation) in a OOP technical sense, of how they are implemented?

How are they actually programmed?

Comment: There's no connection between object storage and OOP concepts that I've seen. The term 'object' used here seems sufficiently generic to be useful, kind of like 'blob' but that was already in widespread use in relational DBs.

Comment: I thought so, but can't be sure without open source code for such a cloud provider storage, to learn more about the implementation. It could be a coincidence when objects are written in OOP languages, maybe they aren't, it just also makes sense to me for the properties, which can be retrieved.

Comment: The implementation of S3 simply exposes an API for you to send a byte stream to an object. What you write is your choice. If it happens to be some serialized form of an OO object from an OOP language then that's what it is. S3 is a disinterested party.

Comment: I used S3 as a tag because it is a very common cloud. My tags shouldn't exclude other familiar cloud services and the question should be seen as pretty abstract. Sorry for that. I can either add any cloud service as tag, so they are flooded, or use no popular one, so this question will probably be left unseen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS S3 is a cloud implementation of object-based storage. Yes it treats files like objects, and there are SDKs for programming (OOP-related) access - for example python implementation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object

However, as I understand, in the background it is more like ORM, not GRCP protocol.

Comment: Your example demonstrates a way, where they are defined in OOP via Python. This solves my initial question for one case. Thanks. I don't doubt that there can be other implementations, but I asked for OOP.